# Removing element from DOM via ng-if bound to attribute directive scope property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I assumed this would be straightforward, but it's seemingly not!

**I'm trying to create a generic attribute directive that will call a method in one of my services and conditionally cause the element in which it is placed to not be added to the DOM if the service method returns false. Basically, ng-if, but an ng-if that internally calls a service method and acts on that**

[Link to Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mixfuE?p=preview)

I have an element containing an attribute directive: e.g

`<p ng-if="visible" my-directive>Hi</p>`

I set `visible` to true in the myDirective directive. I was *expecting* the `<p>` element to be removed from the DOM when `visible` was falsy and added to the DOM when it's truthy. Instead, the ng-if never seems to spot that visible has been set to true in the directive's link function and, hence, the `<p>` element never displays.

I wasn't 100% sure it would work since the directive is removing the element on which it exists, bit of a catch 22 there.

I've spent far too long on this and have so far tried (unsucessfully):

- Adding an ng-if attribute in the link function via these two methods

  - `attr.ngIf = true;`
  - `element.attr('ng-if', true);`
- Changing the ng-if in the `<p>` to ng-show, thereby not removing the element (which I really want to do)

I'm wondering if it's something as simple as scope? Since the ng-if is bound to a property of the `<p>` element, is setting `visible` in the directive scope setting it on the same scope?

On the other hand, I may be drastically over-simplifying, I have a nasty feeling I may have to consider directive compilation and transclusion to get a solution for this.

Does anyone have any feel for where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr:** apparently you want your directive to be self-contained and it should be able to remove and add itself to the DOM. This is possible and makes the most sense via **isolated scope** or **manual manipulation** of the DOM (see below).

**General**
When you do `<p ng-if="visible" my-directive>Hi</p>` angular looks for the `visible` on the current scope, which is the parent scope of the directive. When `visible` is defined, the directive is inserted in the DOM, e.g. taken from your plunker

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p my-directive="showMe" ng-if="visible">I should be shown</p>
</body>`<br>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.visible = 3;
});
```

would make the directive being shown. As you defined an isolated scope on your directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          myDirective: '='
         },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
           scope.visible = (scope.myDirective == 'showMe') ? true : false;
         }
     }
});
```

`scope.visible` in the directive does not affect the `visible` taken into account for `ngIf`.

**Child Scope**
You could define a child scope to get access to the parent scope. If you do that, you can actually affect the right `visible` property, but you have to put it on an object so that the directive can follow the scope prototype chain.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p my-directive ng-if="visibleDirectives.directive1">I should be shown</p>
</body>
```

The `$timeout`s are there for demonstration purposes. Initially the `ngIf` has to evaluate to true else the directive is not being created at all.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.visibleDirectives = { directive1 : true };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope : true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      console.log(scope);
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.visibleDirectives.directive1 = !scope.visibleDirectives.directive1;
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.visibleDirectives.directive1 = !scope.visibleDirectives.directive1;
        }, 2000);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

Like this the directive has to know about the property that defines it's visibility beforehand (in this case `scope.visibleDirectives.visible1`), which is not very practical and prohibits several directives.

**Isolated Scope**
In your example you used an isolated scope. This allows reusing the directive. In order for the directive to be able to modify the appropriate property for `ngIf` you have to again give it the right reference.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p my-directive="directive1" ng-if="directive1.visible">I should be shown</p>
</body>
```

Again you have to provide the property on an object so that the directive can follow the object reference to modify the right `visible`.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.directive1 = {
      visible : true
    };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope : {
      myDirective : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.myDirective.visible = !scope.myDirective.visible;
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.myDirective.visible = !scope.myDirective.visible;
        }, 2000);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

In these cases the directive gets recreated everytime `ngIf` evaluates to true.

**Manual manipulation of the DOM**
You can also just manually remove and append the node of the directive without consulting angular.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p my-directive>I should be shown</p>
</body>
```

In this case you don't need the angular version of `setTimeout` and can even use a `setInterval` as the Interval is created only once, but you have to clear it.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { });

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope : { },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      var el = element[0];
      var parent = el.parentNode;
      var shouldBeShown = false;
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var children = parent.children;
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          if(children[i] === el) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(shouldBeShown) {
          if(!found)
            parent.appendChild(el);
        }
        else {
          if(found)
            parent.removeChild(el);
        }
        shouldBeShown = !shouldBeShown;
      }, 2000);
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Some interesting and quite different approaches there, thanks very much!


I'm liking the "isolated scope" approach. I'd not actually considered passing the property onto which the ng-if is bound to the directive so it can modify it, of course!


Also, the "Manual manipulation of the DOM" is intriguing, I'll do some testing of this, since the elements I'm hiding/showing themselves contain children containing directives, I'm slightly concerned that Angular might get left behind. I guess in that case, manually triggering a digest cycle should bring it back up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element to be removed, use ng-show="visible" this will evaluate as a Boolean and show the element if it evaluates to true. Use "!visible" if you need to flip it.

Also, but adding the scope attribute to your directive you are adding an additional scope, think alternate timeline, that your controller scope that is tied to the page cannot see. That would explain why ng-show may not have worked for you before.